# Boolean hole gets artifacts after boolean modifier is applied and I extrude the hole

Tags: modeling, modifiers, artifacts, boolean-modifier

**1. Cut a hole in this part, right here. Thats why I added the highlightet lines.**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**2. Added a Cylinder, smooth shaded, and auto smooth.**

[image]

**3. First problem arrives. If the cylinder only intersects the upper part of the object I get artifacts. If it scale the cylinder in z direction, so that it intersects the whole object I dont get artifacts, so I do it this way. I also use the "Fast" Solver as this also does not result in artifacts.**

[image]

**4. I apply the boolean and there is my hole. No artifacts. But when I extrude it down, artifacts start to show up. I tried adding supporting lines. I tried extruding the inner faces of the hole and scaling them down. Face normals are correct. I tried "clear costum split normals data" ind the object data" but nothing worked.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Hello could you please share this part of your mesh?

Comment: Do you mean a blend file with only the 2 meshes involved?

Comment: Yes just share the necessary

Comment: I put it at the end of my original post.

Comment: Clear Custom Split Normals Data seems to work?

Comment: But then I get hard edges at the start/end of the bevels

Comment: Don't you want to mark sharp the edges of the hole? You would get rid of this shading

Answer (score 2):

The *Shade Smooth* will smooth the shading between the perpendicular faces, which will give this bad result:

[image]

You can either *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* and play with the *Auto Smooth* value so that it doesn't smooth above 90°, or select the edge loops and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Sharp*:

[image]

Result (note that there's a clipping problem, tweak the clipping values in the N panel):

[image]